# QHD through HDMI on Dell U2715H

Tags: hdmi, displayport

I have an [Acer TimelineX 4820TG](http://www.notebookcheck.net/Review-Acer-Aspire-4820TG-Timeline-X-Notebook.30281.0.html) laptop.

I'd like to buy the [Dell U2715H](http://www1.euro.dell.com/fr/fr/domicile/P%C3%A9riph%C3%A9riques-Dell/dell-u2715h/pd.aspx?refid=dell-u2715h&cs=frdhs1&s=dhs) screen (sorry link in french). It is a **2560x1440 px** display.

*But*

My laptop has only VGA and HDMI port, and the screen has only HDMI and Display port.

Is there any chance i can send the 2560x1440@60hz signal through my HDMI to the screen? Either by direct HDMI (but the screen may put an hard limit on that) or by converting the HDMI to the Display port?

Thank you for any hint, clue, or complete answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the [display’s manual](http://cdn2.bhphotovideo.com/lit_files/104996.pdf), on page 11, there’s a list of supported HDMI “standard” resolutions:

> 480p, 480i, 576p, 720p, 1080p, 576i, 1080i

Further down, on page 12, where they state it’s HDMI 1.4, there’s an important footnote (emphasis mine):

> **Does not support HDMI 1.4 optional specification, includes** HDMI Ethernet Channel (HEC), Audio Return Channel (ARC), standard for 3D format and resolutions, **standard for 2K** and 4K digital cinema resolution.

So, unfortunately, it can’t do anything higher than 1080p via HDMI.

An active HDMI-to-Displayport converter may be available, though finding them will be very hard because the other way (DisplayPort → HDMI) is in much higher demand. It’ll probably be about $100.

**Update**: While researching further, I didn’t find anything. So it seems that no such adapter is available or even announced. I found a single HDMI→DP adapter, which is limited to 1080p.

A few people had success in experimenting with custom display timings at a reduced refresh rate and got an earlier Dell model (U2711) to display 1440p at 50 Hz via HDMI, [see here](http://forums.whirlpool.net.au/archive/1479962) (last posts). Whether this is possible largely depends on your GPU and its drivers.

Comment: Thank you for this long and complete answer. That's what i was afraid of unfortunately. HDMI is highly bound to cinema, video, TV, and i suspect the holders of that format not to allow more exotic use without extra fees... That's really a shame that such screen won't feature a DVI port!

Comment: I found that: http://www.abix.fr/cordons-audio-video/displayport/adaptateurs-displayport/convertisseur-hdmi-vers-displayport-127389.html . It states 4k x 2k @ 30hz, which gives me some hope :) What do you think?

Comment: Looks promising, only 30 Hz though. It’s not terribly expensive either, so why not give it a shot? :)

Comment: 30hz is for 4k x 2k, i need 2.5k x 1.5k, so i hope for 60Hz. I do really not want 30hz. I'm probably buying it soon and i'll give feedback here. Thank you again for help

Comment: Sure. Just make sure to test it without an adapter first. I’m actually a little shocked Dell still hasn’t upgraded the HDMI input to be 2Kish-capable.

Comment: I haven't ever seen an HDMI port able to get WQHD@60Hz on any TFT screen

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that the monitor side supports incoming 2560x1440@60Hz over hdmi cable. I have Intel integrated graphics card and I am able to get stable 2560x1440@60Hz with hdmi.

Comment: You don't indicate which iGPU you have.  The integrated Intel graphic cards are not all created equal.